# Gradle build error after importing Vector Asset

Tags: android, material-design, android-drawable

I'm using Android Studio 1.5 with Gradle Version 2.10 and Android Plugin 1.5.0. I just imported a Material Design icon from the Vector Asset Studio and since then I cannot run de app. I receive this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/alvarohernandogavilan/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are more messages in `Messages` tab of `Android Studio`, please look thoroughly. There might be any library which is being included more than once i guess

Comment: thanks for youtr advice @MustansarSaeed !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to upload your buildToolsVersion on your build.gradle file (app level).

So open the SDK manager, check the last version for "Android SDK Build-tools" and install it. In my case it is 23.0.2

Change to the newer version on your build.gradle:

---

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23

### buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

and run gradle sync. Your problem should be resolved...;)